# dropbox api v1 - when really will stop working

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, deprecated

In official note from Dropbox here: 
https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/
it is stated that 
"we’ll be turning off API v1 a year from now, on 6/28/2017."

Does it mean that until 6/28/2017 dropbox api v1 will be still working ok? 
Or does it mean that they (dropbox) can disable dropbox api v1 any time until 6/28/2017 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox API v1 will continue working until June 28, 2017. A more detailed timeline is available at the bottom of [the blog post](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/).

Comment: I have problem with the search call returning empty set. Recently appeared.

Comment: @powder366 This is a known issue unrelated to the deprecation. We're looking into it.

Comment: @powder366 This should be fixed now.